# Is it possible to programmatically add a button to a surface view or detect a second touch

Tags: android, events, touch

Basically my application detects a tap anywhere on the screen and while the finger is still placed and displays what essentially is a joystick.  While the users finger is still pressed down, they can move the joystick.

What I'm trying to do is add a button on another part of the screen which will always be displayed.  There were two ways I was thinking about going about it.  One was to programmatically add a button and create a listener for it, but from searching around, I don't think there is a way without a view (I'm not using any layout files).

The second way I was thinking was to detect when the user taps in a certain part of the screen, but with my current setup, the user can only do one tap action at a time.

Is it possible to add a button to the surface view or detect two taps at the same time? Here is my current code for onTouch.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClick > 250) {
                    lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    thumbstickToggled = true;
                    thumbstick.setLocation((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                }
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                thumbstickToggled = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                synchronized(getHolder()){
                    thumbstick.moveStick((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                }
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Update:
Solution for what I'm looking for can be found here: [Android Multi-touch event problems...No new touch events while dragging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034660/android-multi-touch-event-problems-no-new-touch-events-while-draging)